# Completely different WinForms executables think they're the same application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've developed two VB Winforms projects. In order to create the second project (project B), I used the first (project A) as a template, copying it to a new directory and renaming it.

I've built the two projects, resulting in two .exe files. If I execute A, it will open. If I then go to execute B, it will not open, instead just bringing the window of A into focus. The sames applies in the opposite situation.

I know that normally executing the same executable twice will have a similar effect: the first execution of A will open window A, all latter executions will bring window A into focus.

However, this behavior is very unexpected when entirely different applications are involved.

Unfortunately, I can't share the projects, nor can I figure out how to reproduce this issue. I'm guessing there's some kind of unique identifier used to tell windows from different applications apart, but I don't know where that could be.

Comment: Try moving your `AssemblyInfo.vb` somewhere else. Reopen the Solution, go to Project → Properties → Application → Assembly Information. Add some data there then click OK. It will generate a new GUID. Rebuild the Solution.

Comment: The important detail that seems to be missing is that you have the Project > Properties > Application > "Make single instance application" option turned on.  Which does go wrong when you copy files.  Click the Assembly Information button, you need another GUID there.  Use Tools > Create GUID to get another one.

Comment: Yea, as they said above. To summarize - if you just copied a project and have not changed the assembly info, output assembly, etc - well, yea. You have two different but same `exe`. They are going to look, behave, etc. - the same